# HttpPostedFileBase sempre vazio ao passar para o controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web

Estou fazendo o envio de um form para meu Controller passando um `HttpPostedFileBase` como parâmetro. O Problema é que ele sempre vem vazio.

**HTML**:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Import","Importacao")" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="fupload" id="label-fupload" class="control-label label-bordered">Clique aqui para escolher um arquivo</label>
    <input type="file" id="fupload" name="fupload" class="fupload form-control border-form" onchange='getFileName()' />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="mes_referencia" class="control-label">Mês</label>
    <input type="text" id="mes_referencia" name="mes_referencia" class="mes_referencia form-control" placeholder="mm/yyyy" />
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" value="Enviar" style="margin-left: 200px;" />
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase fupload){

    if (fupload != null && fupload.ContentLength > 0) {
        dataset = Importador.UploadAndShow(fupload);
    }
    return View(dataset.Tables[0]);
}
```

Já usei o parâmetro `name` igual o parâmetro do Método, assim como `id` e `class`.

Grato!

Comment: Tenta colocar o atributo enctype = "multipart/form-data" no form.

Comment: Leitura: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta colocar o atributo `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` no form.

Comment: Show! Funcionou! Vou dar uma lida no enctype que o amigo @VirgilioNovic mandou. Obrigado :)